# JDBC How to create a procedure using CallableStatement?

Tags: java, jdbc

Would someone who knows how to create a procedure with variables using CallableStatement?

```
Connection targetDBconn = null;
    CallableStatement cs = null;


        try {
    cs = targetDBconn.prepareCall(SqlList.createProcedure_PROC_BACKUP_DATABASE);
        cs.setString(1, targetRmanBackupSettingsInfo.getFile_db_backup());
        cs.execute();
    }
    catch (SQLException ex


        ) {
                            return null;
    }


        finally {if (cs != null) {
            try {
                cs.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
            }
        }
        if (targetDBconn != null) {
            try {
                targetDBconn.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
```

SqlList.createProcedure_PROC_BACKUP_DATABASE like this

```
public static String createProcedure_PROC_BACKUP_DATABASE
            = "CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SYS.PROC_BACKUP_DATABASE\n"
            + "IS \n"
            + " V_TMP VARCHAR2(100);\n"
            + " V_BKP_STATUS VARCHAR2(100);  \n"
            + "BEGIN \n"
            + "\n"
            + " SELECT STATUS INTO V_BKP_STATUS \n"
            + " FROM ( SELECT STATUS\n"
            + "FROM V$RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS\n"
            + "WHERE INPUT_TYPE = 'DB FULL'  \n"
            + "ORDER BY SESSION_KEY DESC) \n"
            + " WHERE ROWNUM = 1;\n"
            + "\n"
            + " IF (V_BKP_STATUS = 'RUNNING') THEN \n"
            + "  RETURN;\n"
            + " END IF; \n"
            + " SELECT OS_COMMAND.EXEC(?) INTO V_TMP FROM DUAL;  \n"
//            + " --SELECT OS_COMMAND.EXEC(?) INTO V_TMP FROM DUAL;\n"
            + "\n"
            + "EXCEPTION\n"
            + "WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND\n"
            + "THEN  \n"
            + "NULL; \n"
            + "WHEN OTHERS \n"
            + "THEN  \n"
            + "-- Consider logging the error and then re-raise \n"
            + "RAISE;\n"
            + "END PROC_BACKUP_DATABASE;\n"
            + "/";
```

there is a question mark inside the query, and I just want to insert some String variable into it. But I execute this code, ora-01003 error occured..

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `SELECT OS_COMMAND.EXEC(?) INTO V_TMP FROM DUAL` within the procedure? Since you can only create a single procedure with the same name, using bind variables within the create statement doesn't make sense. What values would you be passing in here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a `CallableStatement` to *call* a stored procedure. You don't use it to *create* one. A regular `Statement` would be the correct thing to use.

Of course creating the procedure from Java code sounds a bit dubious.

Comment: If then, can I insert a variable into a query? If I should just concatenate strings, I just want to avoid using a regular Statement. How about using PreparedStatement?

Comment: I have a suspicion that `PreparedStatement` won't be of use here, but you can always try.

Comment: yes but I tried using it, same error returned. That's why I try to use CallableStatement :(

Comment: So it seems two wrongs still won't make a right. I guess that's why they call it a `CallableStatement` and not a `CreatableStatement`.

Comment: then is it available to insert a variable using Statement?

Comment: Nope. The only choice is to concatenate Strings. Why are you creating the procedure from Java code anyway? Seems like a brittle approach.

Comment: yes, now I got it, I was stupid. Thanks Kayaman and Mick, I changed it to Regular Statement and concatenated string by string.